# zipping files or a folder into a zip file?

Tags: haxe

I need to know, how to compress files into a zip file?
I found [this](https://gist.github.com/underscorediscovery/8dc3a206c325fbc9a97e) beautiful gist, it will unzip a zip file.

I found `haxe.zip.Compress` but, I didn't find any example about using it, can some please help me in compressing files in haxe?

**EDIT**

Thanks to answer below, I tried Entry:

```
    var fileInput:FileInput = File.read("myfile.xml");
    var bytes:Bytes = Bytes.ofData(File.getBytes("myfile.xml").getData());

    var entry:Entry = {
        fileName:"myfile.xml", 
        fileSize:bytes.length,
        fileTime:Date.now(),
        compressed: false,
        dataSize: 0,
        data: bytes,
        crc32:Crc32.make(bytes)
        };

Tools.compress(entry, 1);
```

But I found that Tools.compress is not implemented for PHP

I tried:

```
Compress.run(bytes, 1);
```

I got:

```
uncaught exception: Not implemented for this platform

Called from haxe.zip.Compress::run
Called from Main::main
```

Although [Compress](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/zip/Compress.html) is mentioned as `Available on all platforms`

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent complete gist would take me some time (and I would have to make sure that everything is working properly), but the direction you should follow is...

You'll need to create an uncompressed `Entry` for each file, compress it with `haxe.zip.Tools.compress` and finally write all entries (`List<Entry>`) with `haxe.zip.Writer.write`.

Comment: please check my EDIT above

Comment: @SamirSabri, I'm afraid `haxe.zip.Compress` is not yet implemented for PHP. There are two main ways of doing it: wrapping some existing PHP function (possibly [gzdeflate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php)) or creating a fully cross-platform `DeflateImpl.hx` (maybe by porting zlib's implementation).

Comment: thanks @jonasmalacofilho , I am writing my PHP app, I will only rely of haxe for xml heavy lifting :)

Answer (score 0):

I though that the haxe.zip package only worked for neko target, not sure. If so, you may need the [format library](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/format).

Comment: I saw that library, but it supports only neko for compress/ uncompress as here https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/format/blob/master/format/zip/Tools.hx

Comment: please check my EDIT above